# How to setup an npm test via mocha?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, electron, mocha.js

I use **Angular** + **TypeScript** + **Electron** and I try to add tests to my application. I installed `mocha` and added the following line to `package.json`:

```
"test": "mocha './**/*.spec.ts'",
```

I have a `app.component.spec.ts` file in my source directory but executing `npm run test` fails with the following exception:

```
> mocha './**/*.spec.ts'
src\app\app.component.spec.ts:1
import { TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
```

Can anyone explain me the context, and how I could fix this issue?

P.S. In similar posts the `module` in `tsconfig.json` needed to be set to `commonjs` which I did, but that didn't solve the issue:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need ts-mocha (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha).

Comment: `npm i --save-dec ts-mocha` didn't solve the issue

Comment: Not only to install it, but also you need to change your test script and call it. Or you can just try it using npx on your terminal root app directory, for example: `npx ts-mocha './**/*.spec.ts'`.